# Non-Standard Arithmetic - order

Tags: logic, model-theory, nonstandard-models

Recently I try to figure out some facts about one specific way of "constructing" a non-standard model for (peano) arithmetic. I guess there are answer to my question already out there, but somehow I cannot find them...

The construction I've in mind goes like this: first let $S_N = (\bar 0, \overline{succ}, \bar +, \bar \cdot)$ be the signature of a first-order language $L(S_N)$ and let $\mathcal{N} = (\mathbb{N}, 0, succ, +, \cdot) $ be a structure of the natural numbers.

Then, set $S' = S \cup\{c\}$ and $\Gamma = Th_{L(S')}(\mathcal{N}) \cup \{ \neg c \equiv 0, \neg c \equiv \overline{succ}(0), \neg c \equiv \overline{succ}(\overline{succ}(0)), \ldots\}$ where $Th_L(\mathcal{M}) := \{ \phi \in Fm_L \mid \mathcal{M} \vDash \phi\}$.

Given the completeness theorem, $\Gamma$ is satisfiable and therefore let $\mathcal{N}^*$ such that $\mathcal{N}^*\vDash \Gamma$.

1. Does this construction work?
2. $S'$ does not contain any relation symbol. So, if one wants to talk about ordering **within the model** $\mathcal{N}^*$ one has to add $\leq$ to the structure $\mathcal{N}$ and to the signature $S_N$, right?
3. Given such a symbol $\leq$, how can one proof that $c^{\mathcal{N}^*} > n$ and not $n_0 < c^{\mathcal{N}^*} < n_1$ where $n, n_0, n_1 \in \mathbb{N}\subseteq |\mathcal{N}^*|$.
4. Is the set $Th_{L(S')}(\mathcal{N}) $ countable? Why?

Thanks for any help.  : )

Comment: One cannot prove within arithmetic that $c$ is greater than every natural number, for the simple reason that we cannot write a sentence that says that. And we do not need a $\lt$ symbol, since instead of $x\le y$ we can use $\exists q\exists r\exists s\exists t(y=x+q^2+r^2+s^2+t^2)$.

Comment: @Andre: Since we're making theories of the natural numbers rather than of integers, you just need $\exists q: x+q = y$.

Comment: True, I was in a Hilbert's tenth problem mood.

Comment: @Hurkyl: The four squares theorem idea can be recycled to show that the polynomials with positive lead coefficient together with $0$ are not a model. For the polynomial $x$ is not a sum of four squares of polynomials. The natural numbers are very much not elementarily equivalent to the polynomials.

Comment: For the countability, sure, there are only countably many sentences.

Comment: Where you wrote that $c$ is not the successor, the double successor, etc. of $c$, you meant to write that it is not the successor, the double successor, etc. of $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and for the correction -- yes. I'm still thinking about the $\exists q : x + q = y$ thing.

Comment: One can prove by induction on $n$ that $\Gamma\vdash c>\overline n$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$.  This is because $\mathcal N\models\forall x\ (x=0\vee x>0)$ and $\mathcal N\models\forall x\ (x>\overline n\rightarrow x=\overline{n+1}\vee x>\overline{n+1})$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$.  Here I am assuming you have the order defined as suggested by others, and $\overline n=\underbrace{\overline{\rm succ}(\overline{\rm succ}(\cdots \overline{\rm succ}(0)\cdots))}_{\text{$n$ $\overline{\rm succ}$'s}}$.